# Find the value that makes maximum in R

Tags: r, dataframe, max

Here I made a simple data `df` to demonstrate what I want to do.

```
df<-data.frame(id=c(2,3,6,8,12,34,27),
               points=c(2,3,5,9,19,2,3))
```

My goal is to find the `id` that has the maximum `points`.
In my example, `19` is the maximum points, so the corresponding `id` is `12`.
In my example, the answer is trivial. But,I want to find `id` that maximizes the `points` using simple R code.

Comment: Try `with(df, id[which.max(points)])#[1] 12`

Comment: It works !  I think I can use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are three ways:

```r
# Base R
df[df$points==max(df$points), "id"]

# dplyr
library(dplyr)
df  |>
    filter(points==max(points))  |>
    pull(id)

# data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[points==max(points), id]
```

The output to all of these is `12`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another strategy:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(-points) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  pull(id)
```

```
12
```

Answer (score 3):

There is also `slice_max()` in `dplyr`.

```r
df %>% 
  slice_max(points)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `which.max` in `base R`

```
with(df, id[which.max(points)])
[1] 12
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `order` in base R

```
> with(df, id[order(-points)][1])
[1] 12
```